# EF Core 6 Upgrade - Deleting Child Object Also Deletes Parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I had an EF Core 2.2 project which I upgraded to EF Core 6.
There is a situation where the user uploads a new set of values for an entity tracked by EF.

The code uses `SetState` to mark the old entity and its child entities as deleted and then sets the value to be the new object.

- In EF Core 2.2 this worked.
- Now in EF Core 6 when `SaveChanges` is called, the parent `ConfigurationSettings` entity is being deleted.
- The parent object is not having its state set to deleted anywhere.

```cs
public void UpdateUserPreferences(UserPreferences newUserPreferences)
{
    var selectedUserConfig = this.database.ConfigurationSettings
        .Include(s => s.UserPreferences)
        .ThenInclude(sc => sc.UserPreference)
        .First(x => x.UserId == 1234);

    selectedUserConfig.UserPreferences.UserPreference
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(up => this.database.SetState(up, EntityState.Deleted);

    this.database.SetState(selectedUserConfig.UserPreferences, EntityState.Deleted);

    selectedUserConfig.UserPreferences = newUserPreferences;

    this.database.SaveChanges();
}
```

After the `SaveChanges` is called, a new `UserPreferences` entity is saved with the updated `UserPreference` child entities which is what we want. However the parent `ConfigurationSettings` entity is being deleted.

The database snapshot is configured with `CascadeDelete`

```cs
    modelBuilder.Entity("ConfigurationSettings", c =>
    {
        c.HasOne("UserPreferences", "UserPreferences")
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("UserPreferencesId")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasConstraintName( "FK_dbo.ConfigurationSettings.UserPreferences_userPreferencesId" );
    }
```

What I want to be happening is that the existing `ConfigurationSettings` entity is not deleted and its `UserPreferencesId` is updated to the newly saved `UpdatedPreferences` entity.

There are no errors being thrown.

Comment: It's possible it's related to [this change in EF Core 3](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10114).

Comment: If you're going to load them anyway, why not go the typical route of removing related entities (`selectedUserConfig.UserPreferences.Clear()`) then add your new ones rather than a "trick the change tracker" approach?

Comment: @Dai Hmm it might. Following the thread, I see that EF Core 3 introduced a change where cascade deletes are performed immediately instead of when SaveChanges is called. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#cascade-deletions-now-happen-immediately-by-default.

Comment: @CaiusJard The example is one of many similar situations in my code base so I was hoping not to have a giant refactoring exercise and configure EF to work like it used to. I will try your suggestion and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: @ChrisB no, EF Core 3 doesn't delete anything immediately. It sets the Deleted state immediately on all related objects.  *Break* the relation first and only then `Remove` the object

Comment: How is the `UserPreferences` entity configured? Post a minimal example that people can actually copy and test

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Could you elaborate on "break the relation first"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appear to have resolved the issue by removing the reference to the parent `ConfigurationSettings` when setting the delete and re-ordering the statements to add the new `UserPreferences` before deleting the old one.

```
public void UpdateUserPreferences(UserPreferences newUserPreferences)
{
    var selectedUserConfig = this.database.ConfigurationSettings
        .Include(s => s.UserPreferences)
        .ThenInclude(sc => sc.UserPreference)
        .First(x => x.UserId == 1234);
   
   var selectedUserPreferences = selectedUserConfig.UserPreferences;

   selectedUserConfig.UserPreferences = newUserPreferences;

    selectedUserPreferences.UserPreference
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(up => this.database.SetState(up, EntityState.Deleted);

    this.database.SetState(selectedUserPreferences, EntityState.Deleted);

    this.database.SaveChanges();
}
```